# STM32F4 - Digital Signal Processing ( DSP )

Tags: c, stm32, dsp, signal-processing, stm32f4

At [this website](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577/LN11/PF252140), I have read that STM32F4 microcontrollers have DSP instructions. To quote:

> It also implements a full set of DSP instructions

I am beginning to learn embedded C programming with CooCox CoIDE and STM32F4 Discovery board.

My question is: How do I make use of DSP instructions, when I am writing code in C? Do I need to include some special libraries / functions?

Comment: Simple answer: If the **tool-chain** provides those functions( or some DSP library) you can use it. So one might need to check the *release notes* of their *tool-chain* version(s) for such feature implementation information(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make use of DSP instructions, when I am writing code in C? Do I need to include some special libraries / functions?

If you see in Datasheet and User Guide and Refrence manual and Programming manual, you will know that you can't find any part with this name> "DSP(unit)" or "DSP instructions set" because the DSP is not a peripheral! it is a part of core. if you see in [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf) and [Technical Data Sheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf) you will see some part like "Chrom-Art Accelerator controller (DMA2D)" that is specialized for image manipulation. YES! this is a part that work by DSP part. the STM32F4 MCUs can work in frequency up to 168 MHz or even 180MHz! then by an special libraries / functions for DSP purpose you can do your job because this clock rate is suitable for this purpose. Enjoy of your MCU, James! :)

Answer (score 2):

ARM has provided a variety of DSP examples as part of their CMSIS (Cortex-M Software Interface Standard), available at [cmsis.arm.com](http://cmsis.arm.com)